# select NULL values within limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the `NULL` values within the limit 100. I.e. the left join should make the output limit 100 and within that I want to count all NULL values. My `subquery` doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

I tried something with `SUM()` but that also won't work

```
SELECT SUM(echonest.id IS NULL) FROM (SELECT *
FROM tracks, echonest
left JOIN echonest ON tracks.id = echonest.id 
LIMIT 100)

SELECT *
FROM tracks AS t
LEFT JOIN echonest AS e ON t.id = e.id
LIMIT 100 IN 
(SELECT COUNT(e.id)
FROM e
WHERE e.id IS NULL)
```

The expected output should count all `NULL` values within the `LIMIT 100`.

Comment: What do you mean "within the limit"?  Sample data and desired results would help (but use a lower limit than 100).

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I think what OP wants is to Select 100 rows, then count the Null values from that.

Comment: Also `LIMIT 100` without using `ORDER BY` is pretty much **meaningless**.. SQL standard defined that SQL tables/resultsets are **orderless** .. Your results are [nondeterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm) (random) now.. To get it deterministic (fixed) you would need to add a column in the `ORDER BY` which is a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key or you know the column have unique values.

Comment: @WEI_DBA yes exactly, that's I want to do. Select 100 rows and count the NULL values from that. thx! :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is what you want

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_nuls
FROM 
(
    SELECT E.id AS eid 
    FROM tracks T
    LEFT JOIN echonest E ON T.id = E.id 
    LIMIT 100
) T
WHERE eid IS NULL
```

However, as specified multiple times in the comments, you should be aware that a `LIMIT` clause without an `ORDER BY` clause will return non-deterministic (aka random) results.

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I thought I was editing my own post, not yours. I don't know how to undo my changes. Maybe just change it back yourself? Your answer is different to mine. Yours will return how many child nulls for a given 100 master records. Mine returns the total child null count up to 100 for all master records. I guess both are valid, depending on what the OP wants. Again, sorry for accidentally editing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just select the top 100 rows and count them like this:-

```
select count(*) from (
    SELECT t.id
    FROM tracks AS t
    LEFT JOIN echonest AS e ON t.id = e.id
    where e.id is null
    limit 100
) a
```

Comment: What about `"I want to count all NULL values"` ?

Comment: What about the **MYSQL** tag..... _note_ MySQL does not have a TOP function

Comment: Won't that always be 100?

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly but TOP is not working on MySQL. Any ideas other ideas?

Comment: Also in SQL Server (MSSQL)/MySQL this comment also using `TOP 100/LIMIT 100` without using `ORDER BY` is pretty much **meaningless**.. SQL standard defined that SQL tables/resultsets are **orderless** .. this query results are nondeterministic (random) now..

Comment: He wants them to be random. It is just a count. And no, top 100 or limit 100 will return up to 100 records, not always 100 records.

Comment: You don't understand mine point..`SELECT t.id
    FROM tracks AS t
    LEFT JOIN echonest AS e ON t.id = e.id
    where e.id is null
    limit 100` can select anny record from the table even the last 100 record from the table or 100 records in the middle from the table.

Comment: He knows that, but he isn't interested in which records they are, because he just wants a number 0-100. That is the point.

Comment: You don't know that from the context of the question.. When i see `LIMIT 100` without `ORDER BY` i assume poeple meant "fetch the first 100" records from the table or resultset.

Comment: Yes, I just want to randomly select 100 rows and count how many NULL values are within that 100. Order by doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree that his question is ambiguous. He says he wants to select the null values but looking at his SQL I'm inclined to agree with Dani Herrera that he in fact wants to count the null values. I might be wrong though, in which case your point stands.

Comment: @EpochGrinder, OP wants to find the `NULL` values of `echonest.id` within the 100 selected rows. Since you are already checking for `echonest.id is null` within the 100, then your count will always be 100. Remove the `Where` clause and `Count(echonest.id)`. I think that would fix it. +1 for effort. :-)

Comment: @WEI_DBA, I think you are indeed correct. The answer below is therefore the correct answer. Or at least it was until I accidentally altered it thinking it was mine! Anyway, Thomas G has cracked it I think.